# Creating a .jinja instance template based on a deployed bitnami VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jinja2, bitnami, google-deployment-manager

I have deployed and configured by Bitnami VM through the Google GUI, as when I deploy through a deployment file (.yaml / .jinja) the password is inaccessible so I cannot configure the VM (Load database, etc.). I now want to use this VM as a "master copy" that my instance template can use to create replicas of this Bitnami VM.

I currently have an instance template and auto-scaler but they deploy a fresh bitnami VM, how would I modify my .jinja files to deploy a replica of my custom bitnami VM instead of a fresh VM?

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:yaml]? There is nothing at all in this post that refers to parsing YAML and  the "template", you present, cannot be converted to valid YAML using jinja2 (I don't see anything jinja2 related in that template, and that certainly is not valid YAML as-is). You should also explain terms like  *fest bitnami VM*

Comment: @Anthon My instance template is a .jinja called by a .yaml file. I have removed .yaml from the tags, but feel jinja should till be there. _fest bitnami vm_ was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance template this link may help:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates

Once you have your instance template you need to create a custom image based on your VM deployment, and then reference that image in your .jinja / .yaml deployment file. This link will help you:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#bundle_image